# How do I populate a fact table from more than one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, fact

I am doing a school assignment but I do not know how to populate a fact table. My query to do it is

```
Select CustomerID from dim_cust
Select ProductID from dim_product
select InvoiceID from dim_invoice

insert into [dim_fact] ([CustomerID], [ProductID], [InvoiceID]);
```

The dim_* are all tables that I filled in manually.

I get also get an "Incorrect syntax near ')'" error.
I also have a column that will have the total number of invoices in the fact table (dim_fact).

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jviAa.png)

[Product Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjaxV.png)

[Invoice Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SgxF.png)

[Customer Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTCZV.png)

[fact table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UBfJ.png)

Comment: Please share table structures of dim_cust, dim_product and dim_invoice tables

Comment: A fact table has more than just values from your dimensions. Though for how to do an `INSERT` have a read of a tutorial or the documentation; you'll see your `INSERT` statement is incomplete.

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that invoice table has both `customerid` and `productid` information. So you can join `dim_cust` and `dim_invoice` table to get what you want.

```
insert into [dim_fact] 
select c.[CustomerID], i.[ProductID], i.[InvoiceID]
from dim_cust c inner join dim_invoice i on c.customerid=i.customerid;
```